# Не работает полиморфизм или я что-то не так делаю?

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

Допустим есть такой код:

```
public interface A {

  void someMethod1();
  void someMethod2();
}

public class B implements A {

    @Override
    public void someMethod1() {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod2() {
        //some code
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    public void methodFromC(){
    //some code
   }
}

public class Main {

    public B mB;

    public void mainMethod(){
        mB = new C();
   }

}
```

В классе `Main`, насколько я понял из темы полиморфизма, я могу так сделать:

```
mB = new C();
```

и `mB` должен быть ссылкой на объект `С`, но в реальности он содержит только методы В.

Что не так я сделал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доступность членов класса через ссылку ограничивается типом ссылки - в данном случае `B`. Чтобы обратиться к методам `C` нужно явно привести его к своему типу:

```
C c = (C) mB;
```

Переменная `c` будет указывать на тот же самый объект, но через неё нам будут доступны методы `C`.

**Но** приведение к дочернему типу возможно только тогда, когда объект на самом деле является экземпляром этого типа или его потомка. То есть был создан конструктором этого типа или его потомка.

Так `mB` не может быть приведён к типу `C`, если он был создан как

```
B mB = new B();
```

или

```
B mB = new D(); // где D тоже потомок B, но не потомок C
```

Comment: ,я реализую данный код в андроиде. сделал так,как Вы посоветовали. компилятор пропустил,и методы доступны, но в процессе запуска приложения ругается: " Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cloniamix.etest.presenter.MainPresenter cannot be cast to com.cloniamix.etest.presenter.PresenterOfSelections", где MainPresenter - родитель

Comment: Значит объект, который Вы пытаетесь привести, на самом деле не является экземпляром `PresenterOfSelections` или его потомком.

Answer (score 3):

`mB` у вас типа `B`, поэтому методы класса `C` к нему не относятся. 
Объявите `mB` типом `С` и все получится:

```
public С mB;
```

Comment: в чем же тогда суть полиморфизма? ведь "В" является родителем "С", соответственно(как писалось в книгах) я могу к ссылке тапа "В" присвоить объект "С"

Comment: Что бы сделать один список с животными, а не два, отдельно для кошек и собак. А если заказчику потребуются еще черепахи, то обслуживание такого кода становится еще дороже.

Comment: @Cloniamix, _один интерфейс - множество реализаций_ - это значит, что если объект присвоен ссылке типа `B`, то Вы можете смело использовать его как тип `B` не задумываясь о том, какого типа он на самом деле

Comment: @Cloniamix, все верно, вы можете к ссылке типа "В" присвоить объект "С", но это не означает, что при этом тип "В" (кстати родительский) примет все методы типа "С". Родительский класс и не должен знать о частных реализациях своих дочерних классов, в нем аккумулируются одинаковые для различных объектов общие характеристики.

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, так, кажется начало проясняться) тогда еще уточните кое-что. если я в "С" переопределю метод из "В", то при таком объявлении: "B mB = new C();"  "mB.someMethod1();" какая версия метода вызовется?

Comment: @Cloniamix, вызовется переопределённая

Comment: Кажется понял механизм)  оказывается не так все сложно, но из-за спутанных мыслей, мозг закипел. спасибо, что помогли разобраться!!!